# как можно улучшить данную нейросеть

Tags: нейронные-сети, python-3.8

Здравствуйте изучаю машинное обучение
и сделал нейросеть небольшую
для распознавания английских заглавных букв ( 26 букв). 50 картинок на каждую букву и 5 проверочных картинок

```
import sys,numpy as np,os
from PIL import Image

def softmax(x,ax=0):
    temp = np.exp(x)
    return temp / np.sum(temp, axis=ax, keepdims=True)

def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)

def tanh2deriv(output):
    return 1 - (output ** 2)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid2deriv(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

def getsymbpercifr(cifr):
    if (cifr==0):
        return "A"
    elif (cifr==1):
        return "B"
    elif (cifr==2):
        return "C"
    elif (cifr==3):
        return "D"
    elif (cifr==4):
        return "E"
    elif (cifr==5):
        return "F"
    elif (cifr==6):
        return "G"
    elif (cifr==7):
        return "H"
    elif (cifr==8):
        return "I"
    elif (cifr==9):
        return "J"
    elif (cifr==10):
        return "K"
    elif (cifr==11):
        return "L"
    elif (cifr==12):
        return "M"
    elif (cifr==13):
        return "N"
    elif (cifr==14):
        return "O"
    elif (cifr==15):
        return "P"
    elif (cifr==16):
        return "Q"
    elif (cifr==17):
        return "R"
    elif (cifr==18):
        return "S"
    elif (cifr==19):
        return "T"
    elif (cifr==20):
        return "U"
    elif (cifr==21):
        return "V"
    elif (cifr==22):
        return "W"
    elif (cifr==23):
        return "X"
    elif (cifr==24):
        return "Y"
    elif (cifr==25):
        return "Z"




def allfls(directory):
    listfls=[]
    listdirs=[]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown = False):
        for name in files:
            str=os.path.join(root, name)
            listfls.append(str)
        for name in dirs:
            str=os.path.join(root, name)
            listdirs.append(str)
    return listfls,listdirs

def sootnsymbnambr(str):
    if (str=='A'):
        return 0
    elif (str=='B'):
        return 1
    elif (str=='C'):
        return 2
    elif (str=='D'):
        return 3
    elif (str=='E'):
        return 4
    elif (str=='F'):
        return 5
    elif (str=='G'):
        return 6
    elif (str=='H'):
        return 7
    elif (str=='I'):
        return 8
    elif (str=='J'):
        return 9
    elif (str=='K'):
        return 10
    elif (str=="L"):
        return 11
    elif (str=="M"):
        return 12
    elif (str=="N"):
        return 13
    elif (str=="O"):
        return 14
    elif (str=="P"):
        return 15
    elif (str=="Q"):
        return 16
    elif (str=="R"):
        return 17
    elif (str=="S"):
        return 18
    elif (str=="T"):
        return 19
    elif (str=="U"):
        return 20
    elif (str=="V"):
        return 21
    elif (str=="W"):
        return 22
    elif (str=="X"):
        return 23
    elif (str=="Y"):
        return 24
    elif (str=="Z"):
        return 25

def getfilesindirtrnab(tkdir):
    fileprovnab = []
    dirname = tkdir
    files = os.listdir(dirname)
    listfileA = list(map(lambda name: os.path.join(dirname, name), files))
    fileprovnab.extend(listfileA[:-5 - 1:-1])
    listfileA = listfileA[0:-5]
    return listfileA,fileprovnab

relu = lambda x: (x >= 0) * x  # returns x if x > 0, return 0 otherwise
relu2deriv = lambda x: x >= 0  # returns 1 for input > 0, return 0 otherwise

def myloadimage(pathimage):
    arr=np.array([])
    im=Image.open(pathimage)
    im=im.convert("L")
    arr=np.array(im.getdata()) #получаем все из картинки
    arr=arr.reshape(28,28)   # получаем амтрицу изображений двумерную 24 на 24
    arr=arr/255-1 #цвет переводим в оттенки серого
    arr=np.abs(arr)  #перевод наоборот (для числа)
    arr2=arr.reshape(784)  #преобразуем двумерную матрицу в вектор
    return arr2

trainnabor=np.zeros((0,784))  #создаем данные тренировочного набора
trainmetk=np.zeros((0,26))

provnabor=np.zeros((0,784))
provmetki=np.zeros((0,26))


(allfls,alldirs)=allfls('C:\/testnab')
for crdir in alldirs:
    (teklistnab,naborprovki)=getfilesindirtrnab(crdir)
    symbol=os.path.basename(crdir)
    chisl=sootnsymbnambr(symbol)
    for tekfl in teklistnab:
        artk=myloadimage(tekfl)
        trainnabor = np.vstack((trainnabor,artk))
        tektrmt = np.zeros((1,26))
        tektrmt[0][chisl] = 1
        trainmetk =np.vstack((trainmetk,tektrmt))
    for tekflp in naborprovki:
        arprov=myloadimage(tekflp)
        provnabor=np.vstack((provnabor,arprov))
        tekprov=np.zeros((1,26))
        tekprov[0][chisl]=1
        provmetki=np.vstack((provmetki,tekprov))


np.random.seed(1)

alpha, iterations, hidden_size, pixels_per_image, num_labels = (0.05,120, 350, 784,26)

weights_0_1 = 0.2 * np.random.random((pixels_per_image, hidden_size)) - 0.1
weights_1_2 = 0.2 * np.random.random((hidden_size, num_labels)) - 0.1
typetrain="sigmoid"
for j in range(iterations):
    error, correct_cnt = (0.0, 0)
    for i in range(len(trainnabor)):
        #тренируем на функцию relu
        if (typetrain=="relu"):
            layer_0 = trainnabor[i:i + 1]
            layer_1 = relu(np.dot(layer_0, weights_0_1))
            layer_2 = np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2)
            error += np.sum((trainmetk[i:i + 1] - layer_2) ** 2)
            correct_cnt += int(np.argmax(layer_2) == np.argmax(trainmetk[i:i + 1]))

            layer_2_delta = (trainmetk[i:i + 1] - layer_2)
            layer_1_delta = layer_2_delta.dot(weights_1_2.T) * relu2deriv(layer_1)

            weights_1_2 += alpha * layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)
            weights_0_1 += alpha * layer_0.T.dot(layer_1_delta)
        elif (typetrain=="sigmoid"):
            #тренируем на сигмоиду
            layer_0 = trainnabor[i:i + 1]
            layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0, weights_0_1))

            # dropout_mask = np.random.randint(2, size=layer_1.shape)
            # layer_1 *= dropout_mask * 2

            layer_2 = softmax(np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2),1)
            error += np.sum((trainmetk[i:i + 1] - layer_2) ** 2)
            correct_cnt += int(np.argmax(layer_2) == np.argmax(trainmetk[i:i + 1]))

            layer_2_delta = (trainmetk[i:i + 1] - layer_2)
            layer_1_delta = layer_2_delta.dot(weights_1_2.T) * sigmoid2deriv(layer_1)
            #layer_1_delta *= dropout_mask

            weights_1_2 += alpha * layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)
            weights_0_1 += alpha * layer_0.T.dot(layer_1_delta)
    if (j%10==0):
        sys.stdout.write("\r" + \
                 " I:" + str(j) + \
                 " Error:" + str(error / float(len(trainnabor)))[0:7] + \
                 " Correct:" + str(correct_cnt / float(len(trainnabor)))+"\n\n")

#проверка
correct_prv=0
for i in  range(len(provnabor)):
    layer_0=provnabor[i]
    prov=provmetki[i]
    layer_1=np.array([1,350])
    if (typetrain=="relu"):
        layer_1 = relu(np.dot(layer_0, weights_0_1))
    elif (typetrain=="sigmoid"):
        layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0, weights_0_1))
    layer_2 = softmax(np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2))
    correct_prv += int(np.argmax(layer_2) == np.argmax(prov))

sys.stdout.write("\r" + "Correct:" + str(correct_prv / float(len(provnabor)))+"\n\n")

#альтернативная проверка
altnb=myloadimage('C:\/transym\prov16.png')
#layer_0=np.zeros((0,784))
#layer_0=np.vstack((layer_0,altnb))
layer_0=altnb
layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0, weights_0_1))
layer_2 = np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2)
layer_2 = softmax(layer_2)

itog=np.argmax(layer_2)  #Номер аргумента буква
symb=getsymbpercifr(itog)
print(str(layer_2))
print(str("Буква: ")+symb)
```

вот собственно процесс обучения нейросети такой

```
I:0 Error:0.06161 Correct:0.962278675904542

 I:10 Error:0.09934 Correct:0.9284064665127021

 I:20 Error:0.05495 Correct:0.9784449576597383

 I:30 Error:0.03268 Correct:0.9953810623556582

 I:40 Error:0.01968 Correct:0.9976905311778291

 I:50 Error:0.01209 Correct:0.9992301770592764

 I:60 Error:0.00727 Correct:1.0

 I:70 Error:0.00417 Correct:1.0

 I:80 Error:0.00236 Correct:1.0

 I:90 Error:0.00130 Correct:1.0

 I:100 Error:0.00069 Correct:1.0

 I:110 Error:0.00037 Correct:1.0

Correct:0.4461538461538462
```

Вроде бы сеть обучает но на проверочном наборе точность как видите 44.6
Подскажите как можно доработать такую нейросеть(не CNN)
чтобы она давала точность ну хотя бы 70-80 процентов на проверочном наборе?
тренировочный набор по ссылке
https://dropmefiles.com/2f3K8

Comment: Я бы начал с `sanity check`: проверил, что вообще в `provmetki`, правильные ли там метки, соответствуют ли они картинкам. И одинаково ли вы вообще закодировали метки трейна и теста я бы проверил. Если всё правильно - начинайте смотреть, где собственно ошибки, в каких образцах: что на самом деле, что предсказалось, посмотрите эти картинки. Возможно, что-то станет понятнее.

Comment: Вообще, была бы стандартная нейросеть на `Keras` каком, было бы проще проверить. А так я не очень понимаю, вы просто по точкам предсказываете? Ну так в проверочном наборе могут быть смещения. Нейросеть "запомнила" трейн, но ничему не выучилась. Для картинок хорошо использовать `convolutions`, есть у вас там слои с конволюциями? Что-то я не уверен. А просто по точкам предсказывать - ну, будут чуть по-другому цифры нарисованы, и всё будет плохо.

Comment: понятно скорее всего нужно реализовывать сверточную нейронную сеть как раз. Я не использую керас на данный момент для понимания нейросетей. Конечно с керасом было бы проще. Наборы проверил все данные пишутся правильные как в тренировочном наборе так и в проверочном

Comment: Да, точно, свёрточную. Забыл как это по русски ))

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем, как изобретать велосипед или хотя-бы делать макет его, я бы ознакомился, а как люди решают аналогичную задачу. В приведенной ниже ссылке автор решает задачу распознавания рукописных букв,  делает это вполне "по взрослому" и в дидактических
целях принципиально не пользуется никакими PyTorch, sci-kit learn, TensorFlow или Keras. Посмотрите,  думаю для себя найдете много чего интересного:
https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-neural-network-from-scratch-8f03c5c50adc